# How to catch NoClassDefFoundError exception to use an optional case?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Sometimes I call `Snackbar.make()` would raise an `NoClassDefFoundError`exception, I'm going to catch it and then show a `Toast` instead, but my below codes can't catch this exception, how can I do it?

```
public static void show(View v, CharSequence snapbarString, CharSequence snapbarTitle) {
    try {
        Snackbar.make(v, snapbarString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(snapbarTitle, new View.OnClickListener()     {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // no implementation required
                    }
                }).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), snapbarString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: what class is missing definition?

Comment: @nandsito the OP who want using default android toast if the library is not present, but his question is catch, so I only provided it simply.

Comment: @holi-java maybe... i found it intriguing that the error is raised only sometimes

Comment: @sunjinbo if you want to use local toast  as an optional one see the second section of my answer.

Comment: @nandsito hi, nandsito. his code has been described clearly which he want an optional one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How to catch a NoClassDefFoundError?

[NoClassDefFoundError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html) is an [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) not an [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). if you really want to catch it, you need catch it as an `Error` not an `Exception`.

```
 try {
    Snackbar.make(v, snapbarString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(snapbarTitle, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // no implementation required
                }
            }).show();
} catch (NoClassDefFoundError e) {
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), snapbarString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

### How to use an optional case if library is not present?

if you want use local toast as an optional one, the advantage of `isSnackbarPresent` is that only checking the library whether present only once. for example:

```
private static final boolean isSnackbarPresent; 

static{                                                             
      isSnackbarPresent = classPresent("${package}.Snackbar");
}

private static boolean classPresent(String className) {
    try {
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}

public static void show(View v
                       , CharSequence snapbarString
                       , CharSequence snapbarTitle) {

  if(isSnackbarPresent){
    Snackbar.make(v, snapbarString, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(snapbarTitle, new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // no implementation required
                }
            }).show();
  }else{
    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), snapbarString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

### Advanced to use an optional case

if you don't want to checking `isSnackbarPresent` every the `show` method called you can do like this:

```
public static void show(View v
                       , CharSequence snapbarString
                       , CharSequence snapbarTitle) {
    toaster.show(v, snapbarString, snapbarTitle);
}

private static final Toaster toaster = classPresent("${package}.Snackbar") 
                                     ? snackbar() 
                                     : locally();

private static Toaster locally() {
    return (view, message, title) -> Toast.makeText(view.getContext()
                                                   , message
                                                   , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
}

private static Toaster snackbar() {
    View.OnClickListener NOTHING = (view)->{};
    return (view, message, title) -> {
        Snackbar.make(view, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction(title, NOTHING).show();
    };
}

interface Toaster {
    void show(View view, CharSequence message, CharSequence title);
}

private static boolean classPresent(String className) {
    try {
        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(className);
        return true;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

### Enhancement

and this pattern is so **flexible** that can choosing one available `Toaster` from all of Toasters, for examples:

```
interface ToasterProvider{
   /**
    *  @see classPresent(String)
    *  @return return true if the library is presented in classpath
    */
   boolean isPresent();
   /**
    * @throws NoSuchElementException thrown if toaster library is not present
    */
   Toaster toaster() throws NoSuchElementException;
}

List<ToasterProvider>  providers = ...;

Toaster toaster = providers.stream()
                           .filter(ToasterProvider::isPresent)
                           .findFirst().map(ToasterProvider::toaster)
                           .orElse(locally());
```